# retorno Json vacio

Tags: nodejs, devexpress

***Hola comunidad soy nueva en nodejs y express y quiero retornar un objeto json pero al llamar la funcion donde tengo los datos del objeto, me retorna un objeto vacio, no se porque no muestra los 10 datos.***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const API_KEY = "";

async function findAll() {
    const url_page = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}&count=10`;
    try{
        const options = {
        "method" : "GET",
        }

        const response = await fetch(url_page,options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(e => {
                console.error({
                    "message":"error",
                    error: e
            })
        })

        return response.map(function(obj){
                return {
                "explanation" : obj.explanation,
                "hdurl" : obj.hdurl,
                "title" : obj.title,
                "url" : obj.url
            };    
        })
    }catch (error){
        return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
}



app.get("/api", async (req,res) =>{

    const allData = findAll()
    
    res.send(allData)  
});

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`server started on port" ${PORT}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

sucede que la respuesta que te devuelve la Api es un objeto `{}`por lo cual no vas a poder iterarlo con `map`, ya que map funciona con arrays `[]`, por lo cual únicamente tienes que devolver las propiedades del objeto que necesites como detallo a continuación:

```
return {
    explanation: response.explanation,
    hdurl: response.hdurl,
    title: response.title,
    url: response.url,
  };
```

Adjunto el código fuente:

```
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const api_key = "DEMO_KEY";

async function findAll() {
  const url_page = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${api_key}`;

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
  };

  const response = await fetch(url_page, options)
    .then((res) => {
      //devolvemos la respuesda de la Api como un json
      return res.json();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      //unicamente retornamos el error como tal para posteriormente capturarlo en el catch.
      return e;
    });

  //En el
  return {
    explanation: response.explanation,
    hdurl: response.hdurl,
    title: response.title,
    url: response.url,
  };
}

app.get("/api", async (req, res) => {
  /* El `try&catch` lo implementamos durante la ejecución de la función `findAll()` */
  try {
    const allData = await findAll();
    res.json(allData);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
});

app.listen(port, console.log(`server started on port" ${port}`));
```

Answer (score -1):

Trata quitando el `async`

```
app.get("/api", (req,res) =>{

    const allData = findAll()
    
    res.send(allData)  
});
```

Comment: Creo que seria bueno que agregaras una breve explicación de tu solución para que le quede mas claro a Yulieth